# If clause and share Point

Tags: sharepoint

Hope this question find you well. I have a question about `if` clause in SharePoint. Is this correct syntax: `=IF(LEN([Phone]) > 10,'Not Correct','Enter New Number')`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct syntax. But if you have problems with this then I can recommend one thing from my experience.
In some locales you must use **semicolon instead of comma** as formula parts delimiter.
Like this:
=IF(LEN([Phone]) > 10;'Not Correct';'Enter New Number')

And may be you can change quotes to double quotes as another attempt.